# C# - expose constant over webservice

Tags: c#, web-services

How would I expose a constant over the webservice?

The constant is below.

```
    public DateTime NullDate = DateTime.Parse("01/01/2000 00:00");
```

Please note, I dont want the use of nullables - exposing this is the only viable option.

Comment: Seems like you would just need to create a service method that returns your constant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Am I missing something?

```
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://www.mynamespace.com")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]        
    public class ConstantService : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {
        public const DateTime NullDate = DateTime.Parse("01/01/2000 00:00");


        [WebMethod]
        public DateTime getNullDate()
        {                
            return NullDate;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Depends what WebService are you using. AFAIK it's not possible to expose it in WCF.
You could just expose it as method. Like GetNullData()

Answer (score 2):

You can't expose a constant over a web service, but you could expose a method that returned the constant or use an enumeration or boolean to determine if the null date should be used.

```
public const DateTime NULL_DATE_CONST = DateTime.Parse("01/01/2000 00:00");

[WebMethod]
public DateTime NullDate()
{
    return NULL_DATE_CONST;
}
```

This would be accessed like a method using `()`, but it would behave as a property of sorts.

Answer (score 1):

Web services have no properties nor fields, so you need to create a method to provide this value. Alternatively, return it as part of the response to some other method which usage needs this const value.